# XY coordinates on bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, scaling, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I am developing one android application, in that I am getting one bitmap image from server and also getting x and y coordinates from server.  Those X and Y coordinates is nothing but user location.  Now my problem is if I run that app in mobile it is working fine.  But in tabs I need to resize the bitmap size, if I resize that bitmap those x and y coordinates are also changing. This is not map related application.  How can I resize bitmap without effect to x and y coordinates ? This is not map related application.

Comment: Are X and Y here means latitude and longitude and you are showing some where on image. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Those x and y coordinates are not lat and long.

Answer (score 1):

I think,You can simply calculate it

For Example,

```
OriginalWidth = 100;
OriginalHeight = 100;
OriginalX = 30;
OriginalY = 30;


NewWidth = 200;
NewHeight = 200;

Then,

NewX = (OriginalX * NewWidth)/OriginalWidth = 60;
NewY = (OriginalY * NewHeight)/OriginalHeight = 60;
```

---

Please do google on how to get width and height of image.

Comment: i am getting that bitmap image's width and height from server

Comment: Still changes in xy coordinates.

Comment: Try to convert everything into pixel first, like height,width,x,y ... original values into pixel and then use above calculations

Comment: how to convert feet into pixels.

Comment: {
        "x": 40.16004,
         "y": 15.030116,
        "z": 0,
        "unit": "FEET"
         }, this is one json object, i am getting like this

Comment: Though they say it, forget it.  1. Take image and load into MS Paint. 2. Put marker on the location where it should be(you should know it hardly) 3. Now see the ratio if image and marker position 4. Now resize whole paint image by 50,100% and again check ratio.. now you know the 40 X is which pixcel in your image before and after, and understand the ration and then apply calculation

Comment: Hi  MKJParekh. I am getting one issue. i.e., i have to show 2 scenarios on bitmap. one is user location, second is direction to particular location. I am getting individually two scenarios. But if i combine two scenarios i.e, if i show direction to path user location is path point is overriding. How to solve this issue. Please help me

Comment: I didn't get you completely, anyways do -1,-2 or -10 in x and y position values of user. Make some minor changes in XY location in the application side or just simple first draw path and then put marker points means change the sequence of code. @user5594218